# Is $f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & x\in(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]\\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$ differentiable at 0?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, derivatives

I have the function $f:\mathbb{[0,1]\to R}$ defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & x\in(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]\\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$$

and I must show whether or not $f$ is differentiable at $0$. My first idea was to see if it was discontinuous at $0$, however I found that it was in fact continuous, so now I know that $\underset{x\to 0}{\lim} f(x)=0$ but this doesn't help me to see if it is differentiable at $0$. I know I must show whether the limit $$\underset{x\to 0}{\lim} \frac{f(x)}{x}$$ exists but I have no idea where to begin with this as my intuition would be to check both sides of the limit, however, $f$ is not well defined for $x<0$ so I can't do that. Is there something obvious I'm missing? This has been bugging me for a while now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any number  $x \in (0,1)$ lies in $(\frac 1 {n+1}, \frac  1 n)$ for some $n$. Note that  $\frac {f(x)} x$ lies between $\frac {1/n} {1/n}$ and $\frac {1/n} {1/(n+1)}$. Conclude that $|\frac {f(x)} x-1| <\epsilon$ provided $\frac 1 n <\epsilon$ which is true if $x <\epsilon /2$.

[ $\frac 1  n <x(1+\frac  1 n) \leq 2x$].

Comment: Kavi.Very nice!!

Answer (score 0):

Since $0$ the left endpoint of the domain of $f$, you can only consider the right derivative.

You have that $$\frac x{1-x}≤f(x)≤x.$$ Then $$\frac 1{1-x}≤\frac{f(x)}x≤1.$$ By squizzing, $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x=1.$$